# send messages to an IM using chat.facebook

Tags: facebook, api

I have a scenario where people login to the IM we developed using the facebook credentials. We send chat messages so that the other user on the IM can process the message. Now I need these IMs to send messages among them that do not show up in the other user's chat window or get stored in the messages history. How can we achieve this with facebook chat?(with facebook we do not get the user's JID directly, rather we get an Id and the translation happen internally)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is here - what API are you using, and what isn't working correctly? It sounds like you want to send messages using Facebook's XMPP server without those messages being visible in Facebook's interface, but that doesn't make much sense

Comment: Yeah, we are trying to send messages among our IMs and that do not get stored in the chat history(as they won't make sense to users). These messages are not chat messages that user enters but they are control messages to instruct our IM to perform certain operations.

We use Smack API to log into the facebook's XMPP chat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment above, this is not a feature of the API - messages sent on a user's behalf via the API will always appear in that user's messages list - you can't 'invisibly send' messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware that we can't directly send invisible messages, but is there a provision to register a resource with the facebook's XMPP chat server and then send messages to an user on that resource or some other work around like that?

Comment: No, i don't think so - if you need messages to go between users, but without them seeing the messages, you'll need to set up your own message server or backend